# Can't convert my string to hex representation

Tags: c#

I'm receiving data using serial port, and I'm use the following code to convert the string to hex representation and show it in the richtextbox5:

```
string hex = "";
            foreach (char c in RXstring)
            {
                uint tmp = c;
                hex += String.Format("{0:X2}", (uint)System.Convert.ToInt16(tmp.ToString())) ;
            }

            richTextBox5.AppendText(hex + "   <= Hex");
```

where RXstring is where I store data from serial port.
 The **problem** is :
when I send data like 127(decimal)=> 01111111(binary)=> 7F(hex) it converted correctly, while when I send data like 191 or 167 which all share that the most significant bit is 1 and they are all 8 bits the **output** is 3F despite the other bits, (the representation of any 8 bits start with 1 is 3F), whats wrong with my code?
can you help, thx.

Comment: you should treat what is coming over the serial port as raw bytes, not a string. you should make sure you use the right encoding!

Comment: Show your send code, and more of your receive code.

Comment: Are you sure a `char` is the correct data format for reading raw data? I would use `byte` instead. It is designed to read UTF-16 characters, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of using bytes - and it seems to work as you want:

```
        string hex = "";
        byte[] RXstring = { 0xFF, 0xCF, 0xB8, 167,191 };
        foreach (byte c in RXstring)
        {
            uint tmp = c;
            hex += String.Format("{0:X2}", (uint)System.Convert.ToInt16(tmp.ToString()));
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine("{0}   <= Hex", hex);
```

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't worked as I expected, since I'm reading from a serial port RXstring must be a string, otherwise, I'm not able to use :
RXstring = serialPort1.ReadExisting();

Answer (score 0):

I just add `serialPort1.Encoding = Encoding.Default;` to my serial port and worked perfectly